# Attaching script to object during runtime doesn't work. New to unity3d. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I looked in the forums as well, and all they really say is use the GameObject.AddComponent API, but well, that doesn't seem to work.
Here's my code (C#):

```
GameObject someGameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(somePrefab, position, rotation);
BlueColour script = someGameObject.AddComponent<BlueColour>();
```

I run the scene, and nada, the script does not execute.
I tried `script.enabled = true;` too and nothing.
Also, it works fine if I attach it from the Inspector through "Add Component" button.

Help? :) Please...

Thank you!

Edit1: You asked for the BlueColour.cs script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BlueColour : MonoBehaviour {

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
        print ("It started!");
    }

    void Update () {

        print("It's updating!");
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        print("Detected collision between " + gameObject.name + " and " + collisionInfo.collider.name);

        print("There are " + collisionInfo.contacts.Length + " point(s) of contacts");

        print("Their relative velocity is " + collisionInfo.relativeVelocity);
    }

    public void Yowza()
    {

    }
}
```

None of the methods trigger/execute.

I also added a line after it to change the material colour:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
```

which also doesn't work. Everything works fine through the Inspector. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the script does not execute? What doesn't work? Can you post the `BlueColour` script?

Comment: Is the script attached successfully to your gameobject ?

Comment: Sure, here's the BlueColour script:

Comment: As per Hellium's question; have you checked if the script is actually being added by inspecting it in the editor?

Comment: Uhh... well I want to add the script through coding, so no.

Comment: What I have is GameObjectOne, which has a script attached. This script is the script that instantiates someGameObject and attaches BlueColour.cs to someGameObject as per my original post.

Comment: Well I think you'll find it's being attached but you are not getting your log message from `Start()` as it's not running.  Try changing that `Start()` method to `OnEnable()`.

Comment: To make it clear, I have one object. I attached script "SomeScript.cs" to it. Sometimes during execution, the instantiaton of someGameObject and subsequent BlueColour.cs attachment to someGameObject occurs as per my first post. Please help :(

Comment: No, still doesn't work, Droppy. OnEnable() does not work.

Comment: "Uhh... well I want to add the script through coding, so no".  You do realise you can select objects in the scene editor and view their properties while the game is running?  You might want to pause the game to do this.

Comment: Ah, very useful, right. Thank you Droppy. :)

Comment: Also you can disable the "Maximize on Play" in order to keep your Hierarchy and Inspector visible without having to pause the game. (I remember finding it only after a few weeks... )

Comment: Have you got any error in your console ?
 ----- 
Maybe dumb question, but, are you sure the first lines of code, instantiating your object and attaching the script, are called ?
 ----- 
Can you confirm the BlueColour script is successfully attached to your instantiated gameobject when game is running ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that those 2 line of code is executed.

   ```
   GameObject someGameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(somePrefab, position, rotation);
   BlueColour script = someGameObject.AddComponent<BlueColour>();
   ```

   You can put a `Debug.Log()` to confirm.
2. If they are executed then make sure your `somePrefab` is not
   `pre-disabled`. You can check it by selecting your prefab in the `Project` tab. Then look at the top of the `Inspector` right at the left of the name text box. There is a small check box. Make sure it is **checked**.
3. Or you could simply `someGameObject.SetActive(true);`

[image]